# trie or balanced binary search tree to store dictionary?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dictionary, tree

I have a simple requirement (perhaps hypothetical):

I want to store english word dictionary (n words) and given a word (character length m), the dictionary is able to tell, if the word exists in dictionary or not.
What would be an appropriate data structure for this?

a balanced binary search tree? as done in C++ STL associative data structures like set,map

or

a trie on strings

**Some complexity analysis:**
in a balanced bst, time would be (log n)*m   (comparing 2 string takes O(m) time character by character)

in trie, if at each node, we could branch out in O(1) time, we can find using O(m), but the assumption that at each node, we can branch in O(1) time is not valid. at each node, max possible branches would be 26. if we want O(1) at a node, we will keep a short array indexible on characters at each node. This will blow-up the space. After a few levels in the trie, branching will reduce, so its better to keep a linked list of next node characters and pointers.

what looks more practical? any other trade-offs?

Thanks,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd say use a Trie, or better yet use its more space efficient cousin the [Directed Acyclic Word Graph (DAWG)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph).

It has the same runtime characteristics (insert, look up, delete) as a Trie but overlaps common suffixes as well as common prefixes which can be a big saving on space.

Comment: Since the only requirement specified by the OP is key retrieval, I'm not seeing why a Trie is a better data structure than a Hash Table.  Hash table will perform better than a Trie and is simpler to implement.  In the context of C++ STL, you can use std::unordered_set

Comment: @minism, Other answers and comments have pointed out the same.  The original question mentioned trie vs. map, so my thinking went along that route.  A good hashmap (particularly if you can use std::unordered_set) is probably an even better solution.

Answer (score 4):

If this is C++, you should also consider `std::tr1::unordered_set`.  (If you have C++0x, you can use `std::unordered_set`.)

This just uses a hash table internally, which I would wager will out-perform any tree-like structure in practice.  It is also trivial to implement because you have nothing to implement.

Comment: +1 The stated requirement is just fast lookup, with no requirements re sorting, resizing, random access, insertion/deletion etc.. Hash maps are well suited, and as you say could be faster - the hashing time is countered by typically jumping directly to the required bucket, whereas trees need to access many intermediate pages pages - thrashing the cache more. Depends on hardware/OS/system-load/dictionary size etc..

Answer (score 3):

Binary search is going to be easier to implement and it's only going to involve comparing tens of strings at the most.  Given you know the data up front, you can build a balanced binary tree so performance is going to be predictable and easily understood.

With that in mind, I'd use a standard binary tree (probably using `set` from C++ since that's typically implemented as a tree).

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to store the dict as sorted, \n-separated words on disk, load it into memory and do a binary search. The only non-standard part here is that you have to scan backwards for the start of a word when you're doing the binary search.

Here's some code! (It assumes globals `wordlist` pointing to the loaded dict, and `wordlist_end` which points to just after the end of the loaded dict.

```
// Return >0 if word > word at position p.
// Return <0 if word < word at position p.
// Return 0 if word == word at position p.
static int cmp_word_at_index(size_t p, const char *word) {
  while (p > 0 && wordlist[p - 1] != '\n') {
    p--;
  }
  while (1) {
    if (wordlist[p] == '\n') {
      if (*word == '\0') return 0;
      else return 1;
    }
    if (*word == '\0') {
      return -1;
    }
    int char0 = toupper(*word);
    int char1 = toupper(wordlist[p]);
    if (char0 != char1) {
      return (int)char0 - (int)char1;
    }
    ++p;
    ++word;
  }
}

// Test if a word is in the dictionary.
int is_word(const char* word_to_find) {
  size_t index_min = 0;
  size_t index_max = wordlist_end - wordlist;
  while (index_min < index_max - 1) {
    size_t index = (index_min + index_max) / 2;
    int c = cmp_word_at_index(index, word_to_find);
    if (c == 0) return 1;  // Found word.
    if (c < 0) {
      index_max = index;
    } else {
      index_min = index;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

A huge benefit of this approach is that the dict is stored in a human-readable way on disk, and that you don't need any fancy code to load it (allocate a block of memory and read() it in in one go).

If you want to use a trie, you could use a packed and suffix-compressed representation. Here's a link to one of Donald Knuth's students, Franklin Liang, who wrote about this trick in his thesis.

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.123.7018&rep=rep1&type=pdf

It uses half the storage of the straightforward textual dict representation, gives you the speed of a trie, and you can (like the textual dict representation) store the whole thing on disk and load it in one go.

The trick it uses is to pack all the trie nodes into a single array, interleaving them where possible. As well as a new pointer (and an end-of-word marker bit) in each array location like in a regular trie, you store the letter that this node is for -- this lets you tell if the node is valid for your state or if it's from an overlapping node. Read the linked doc for a fuller and clearer explanation, as well as an algorithm for packing the trie into this array.

It's not trivial to implement the suffix-compression and greedy packing algorithm described, but it's easy enough.

Answer (score 1):

Industry standard is to store the dictionary in a hashtable and have an amortized O(1) lookup time. Space is no more critical in industry especially due to the advancement in distributive computing.

hashtable is how google implement its autocomplete feature. Specifically have every prefix of a word as a key and put the word as the value in the hashtable.

Comment: Lookup time in a dictionary is `O(m)` time (where `m` is the length of the key) just like with a Trie. In fact there is no data structure can violate that minimum bound, since you need to read the whole key to know for sure which value you want to read.